# Elastic search negate phrase and words in simple query string

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I'm trying to negate some words and phrases in an Elastic Search request using the simple query string.

This is what I do:

`&q=-"the witcher 3"-game-novel`

So basically, trying to negate a phrase AND the words after it. But that doesn't seem to work.
If I try to negate the words alone it works.
How can I negate phrases and sentences in a simple query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result.

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"test"
}
{
    "name":"game"
}
{
    "name":"the witcher"
}
{
    "name":"the witcher 3"
}
{
    "name":"the"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "-(game | novel) -(the witcher 3)",
        "fields": ["name"],
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64133051",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "the"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64133051",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "the witcher"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64133051",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "test"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Bouji did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Thank you, I did. Does the phrase negation only match exact phrases? Then that would indeed solve my problem.

Comment: Yes @Bouji, it will match the exact phrase. As you can see in my search query above, the data containing `the witcher 3`, is not retrieved, apart form that data having `the` and `the witcher` is returned.